# Show product details based on row click of product list page using vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a data table with products list. In my mock application, i am clicking any row of product list data table it will route to Product details of that particular product.

So idea is that  - There are two json. 1. Product.json 2. ProductDetails.json. Now, i want to filter out based on id ( product id === productDetails id) in vuex. So i can get a state of current product and view into UI.

**Here is my mock Product json**

```
    {
    "data": [
        {
    id: 'Apple224',
    category: 'phone',
    brand: 'apple',
    price: 4241.499828399639,
    
}, {
    id: 'Huawei221',
    category: 'phone',
    brand: 'huawei',
    price: 1823.6625483451157,
}]
```

}

**Here is my Product details json**

```
    { 
      productDetails: [
         {
           Id: 'Apple224',
           images: ['https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/18/280-413/9801258663986.jpg?v1', 'https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/18/280-413/9801258696754.jpg?v1', 'https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/18/280-413/9801258729522.jpg?v1', 'https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/18/280-413/9801258762290.jpg?v1'],
    brand: 'apple’,
    keyDetails: [{
        price: 4241.499828399639,
        cpu: '1.3GHz Apple A6',
        camera: '8mp (3264x2448)',
        size: '124.4mm x 59.2mm x 8.97mm (4.9 x 2.33 x 0.35)',
        weight: '132 grams (4.7 ounces) with battery',
        display: '4.0 326 pixel density',
        battery: '1480 mAh’,
   }]
    otherDescription:[{
        memory: '16GB, 32GB and RAM 1 GB',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam 
        aspernatur!’
   }]   
    }, 
    {
    Id: 'Huawei221',
    images: ['https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/21/280-413/9933217792050.jpg?v1', 'https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/21/280-413/9933217628210.jpg?v1', 'https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/21/280-413/9933217660978.jpg?v1', 'https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/21/280-413/9933217693746.jpg?v1'],
    brand: 'huawei’,
    keyDetails: [{
        price: 1823.6625483451157,
        cpu: '1.3GHz Apple A6',
        camera: '8mp (3264x2448)',
        size: '124.4mm x 59.2mm x 8.97mm (4.9 x 2.33 x 0.35)',
        weight: '132 grams (4.7 ounces) with battery',
        display: '4.0 326 pixel density',
        battery: '1480 mAh’,
   }]
    otherDescription: [{
        memory: '16GB, 32GB and RAM 1 GB',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam 
        aspernatur!’
   }]
  },
 ]
}
```

Now, here is my service
**Service**

```
    export async function getProducts() {
    let resp = await http.get('/products');
    return resp.data;
}
export async function getProductDetails() {
    let resp = await http.get('/productsDetails');
    return resp.data;
}
```

**Vuex actions**

```
const actions = {
async fetchProducts({ commit }) {
    const prodts = await service.getProducts();
    commit('SET_PRODUCT_LIST', prodts);
},
async fetchProductsDetails({ commit }) {
    const prodctDetails = await service.getProductDetails();
    commit('SET_PRODUCT_DETAILS', prodctDetails);
}
```

};

**Vuex mutation**

```
// need to update state for each row click to get particular product details
```

I am not able to understand how will i handle into vuex and send the updated state to UI .. So, UI will only route and show the details.